# Register a Mono application to an Uri scheme on OSX

Tags: c#, macos, mono, url-scheme

Hello I'm developping an application for Windows and Mac that register to an uri scheme

```
    static void RegisterURI()
    {
        if (Environment.OSVersion.Platform.ToString() == "Unix") //I'll never use it on any linux machine so it should be OK
        {
            //What should I put HERE ??
        }
        else
        {
            //on récupère le chemin de l'assembly
            string MyPos = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program)).Location;

            var protocol = Registry.ClassesRoot
                .CreateSubKey("serialcodereader");
            protocol.SetValue("", "URL:Lancer l'écouteur de liseuse de code barre COM");
            protocol.SetValue("URL Protocol", "");
            var icon = protocol.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon");
            icon.SetValue("", MyPos + ",1");
            var command = protocol.CreateSubKey("shell").CreateSubKey("open").CreateSubKey("command");
            command.SetValue("", '"' + MyPos + '"');
        }
    }
```

Here is the code I use for Windows but how can I do it for OSX ?

ps: good to know: I never used any Mac or even Iphone in my life, so stay simple whith those strange animals :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in something similar to that.
I do suggest to waste some time inspecting this: **NSBundle.MainBundle.InfoDictionary.ToString()**

And check this source code: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/main/src/addins/MacPlatform/MacPlatform.cs
because they're using NSBundle structure to change it at runtime.

As quickly as I found some solution, I will share with you.

---

I had arrived to a functional solution.

1. I picked some info from this blog: https://mhut.ch/journal/2010/01/24/creating_mac_app_bundle_for_gtk_app and modified the script there
2. I wrote a single C#/Gtk application using Mono in order to be reusable in Windows/Linux environment
3. In that application I used the some approach you use in order to associate the URL schema in Windows environment.
4. I wrote a .ini file describing my application
5. I wrote a bash script that takes the compiled application, the .ini file, the icons and create a Apple Bundle file
6. I tested with single URL calling from html page

**myProject.ini**

```
[project]
CFBundleExecutable=ExecutableName
CFBundleName="Human Readable Executable Name"
CFBundleVersion="1.0"
REV_DOMAIN="com.sample"
URLScheme="myapp"
# src is where Mono left your executable
src='/Users/myself/Projects/MyApp/MyApp/bin/Release/'
CFBundleURLIconFile='appicons.icns'
```

**Usage sample:**

```
$ build-mac-app.sh myProject
```

This will produce a folder with  '.app' extension and all the stuff inside you need to run it.
First, remember to run it one in order to MacOS make the association and second, pay attention to the usage of the scheme because if you had used the url scheme with other development it will fail or open the other application.

**The HTML test file**

<a href="**myapp**://coisa-a-ser-assinada">clique para testar o assinador</a>

***The builder script***

I wrote it originally in pt-br as it was originally developed *today* for internal usage

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ""
echo "EDortta/build-mac-app.sh"
echo "Construtor de aplicativos para MacOSx"
echo "Este script usa a saída gerada por MonoDevelop C#/Gtk"
echo "e produz um Mac App Bundle pronto para ser distribuido"
echo "------------------------------------------------------"
if [ -f "$1" ]; then
  config="$1"
  CFBundleExecutable=`cat $config | sed -n '/\[project\]/,/\[.*\]/p' | awk -F= '/CFBundleExecutable/{print $2}' | tr -d '"' | tr -d "'"`
  CFBundleName=`cat $config | sed -n '/\[project\]/,/\[.*\]/p' | awk -F= '/CFBundleName/{print $2}' | tr -d '"' | tr -d "'"`
  CFBundleVersion=`cat $config | sed -n '/\[project\]/,/\[.*\]/p' | awk -F= '/CFBundleVersion/{print $2}' | tr -d '"' | tr -d "'"`
  REV_DOMAIN=`cat $config | sed -n '/\[project\]/,/\[.*\]/p' | awk -F= '/REV_DOMAIN/{print $2}' | tr -d '"' | tr -d "'"`
  CFBundleURLIconFile=`cat $config | sed -n '/\[project\]/,/\[.*\]/p' | awk -F= '/CFBundleURLIconFile/{print $2}' | tr -d '"' | tr -d "'"`
  URLScheme=`cat $config | sed -n '/\[project\]/,/\[.*\]/p' | awk -F= '/URLScheme/{print $2}' | tr -d '"' | tr -d "'"`
  src=`cat $config | sed -n '/\[project\]/,/\[.*\]/p' | awk -F= '/src/{print $2}' | tr -d '"' | tr -d "'"`

  echo "src=$src"

  if [ ! -d "$CFBundleExecutable.app" ]; then
    mkdir "$CFBundleExecutable.app"
    rsync -rvt mac-skel/* "$CFBundleExecutable.app/"

    sed -i -e "s/%CFBundleExecutable%/$CFBundleExecutable/g" "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/Info.plist"
    sed -i -e "s/%CFBundleName%/$CFBundleName/g" "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/Info.plist"
    sed -i -e "s/%CFBundleVersion%/$CFBundleVersion/g" "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/Info.plist"
    sed -i -e "s/%REV_DOMAIN%/$REV_DOMAIN/g" "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/Info.plist"
    sed -i -e "s/%URLScheme%/$URLScheme/g" "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/Info.plist"
    sed -i -e "s/%CFBundleURLIconFile%/$CFBundleURLIconFile/g" "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/Info.plist"

    if [ -f "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/Info.plist-e" ]; then
        rm -f "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/Info.plist-e"
    fi

    if [ -f "$CFBundleURLIconFile" ]; then
        cp "$CFBundleURLIconFile" "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/Resources/$CFBundleExecutable.icns"
    fi

    mv "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/MacOS/appname.sh" "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/MacOS/$CFBundleExecutable.sh"
    cp -r "$src/" "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/MacOS/"

    sed -i -e "s/%CFBundleExecutable%/$CFBundleExecutable/g" "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/MacOS/$CFBundleExecutable.sh"
    sed -i -e "s/%CFBundleName%/$CFBundleName/g" "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/MacOS/$CFBundleExecutable.sh"

    if [ -f "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/MacOS/$CFBundleExecutable.sh-e" ]; then
        rm -f "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/MacOS/$CFBundleExecutable.sh-e"
    fi

    chmod +x "$CFBundleExecutable.app/Contents/MacOS/$CFBundleExecutable.sh"

  else
    echo "$CFBundleExecutable.app já existe"
    echo "Por favor, considere remover a pasta"
  fi
else
    echo "Indique o seu projeto C#/GTK"
    echo "Caso precise de um exemplo, use project-sample.ini"
fi
```

***Behind the scenes structures***

At the same lever of 'build-mac-app.sh' and the application icons (moved or copied from the project or other source) there is a mac-skel folder with these files:

```
mac-skel/
└── Contents
    ├── Info.plist
    ├── MacOS
    │   └── appname.sh
    └── Resources
```

**mac-skel/Contents/Info.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>pt-br</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>MacOS/%CFBundleExecutable%.sh</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>../Resources/%CFBundleExecutable%.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>%REV_DOMAIN%.%CFBundleExecutable%</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>%CFBundleName%</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>%CFBundleVersion%</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>xmmd</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>%CFBundleVersion%</string>
    <key>NSAppleScriptEnabled</key>
    <string>NO</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLIconFile</key>
            <string>%CFBundleURLIconFile%</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>%REV_DOMAIN%.%CFBundleExecutable%</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>%URLScheme%</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**mac-skel/Contents/MacOS/appname.sh**
*This is the one took from the blog showed before*

```
#!/bin/sh

#get the bundle's MacOS directory full path
DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)

#change these values to match your app
EXE_PATH="$DIR\%CFBundleExecutable%.exe"
PROCESS_NAME="%CFBundleExecutable%"
BUNDLENAME="%CFBundleName%"

#set up environment
MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH="$DIR:$MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/lib:/lib:/usr/lib"
export PATH="$MONO_FRAMEWORK_PATH/bin:$PATH"

#mono version check
REQUIRED_MAJOR=2
REQUIRED_MINOR=4

VERSION_TITLE="$BUNDLENAME Não pode ser aberta"
VERSION_MSG="$BUNDLENAME requer o Framework Mono versão $REQUIRED_MAJOR.$REQUIRED_MINOR ou  posterior."
DOWNLOAD_URL="http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html"

MONO_VERSION="$(mono --version | grep 'Mono JIT compiler version ' |  cut -f5 -d\ )"
MONO_VERSION_MAJOR="$(echo $MONO_VERSION | cut -f1 -d.)"
MONO_VERSION_MINOR="$(echo $MONO_VERSION | cut -f2 -d.)"
if [ -z "$MONO_VERSION" ] \
    || [ $MONO_VERSION_MAJOR -lt $REQUIRED_MAJOR ] \
    || [ $MONO_VERSION_MAJOR -eq $REQUIRED_MAJOR -a $MONO_VERSION_MINOR -lt $REQUIRED_MINOR ] 
then
    osascript \
    -e "set question to display dialog \"$VERSION_MSG\" with title \"$VERSION_TITLE\" buttons {\"Cancelar\", \"Baixar...\"} default button 2" \
    -e "if button returned of question is equal to \"Baixar...\" then open location \"$DOWNLOAD_URL\""
    echo "$VERSION_TITLE"
    echo "$VERSION_MSG"
    exit 1
fi

#get an exec command that will work on the current OS version
OSX_VERSION=$(uname -r | cut -f1 -d.)
if [ $OSX_VERSION -lt 9 ]; then  # If OSX version is 10.4
    MONO_EXEC="exec mono"
else
    MONO_EXEC="exec -a \"$PROCESS_NAME\" mono"
fi

#create log file directory if it doesn't exist
LOG_FILE="$HOME/Library/Logs/$BUNDLENAME/$BUNDLENAME.log"
mkdir -p "`dirname \"$LOG_FILE\"`"

#run app using mono
$MONO_EXEC $MONO_OPTIONS "$EXE_PATH" $* 2>&1 1> "$LOG_FILE"
```